# Can not give an empty list to Python function throws "TypeError"

Tags: python, list, python-3.6, nonetype, empty-list

The function is supposed to print out all the bit vetcors that are n bits long and contain k 1's. The problem is that I can not give an empty list as an input to the function.

I am working on Ubuntu and using Python 3.6. I have also tried to use a non empty list like [1], but this throws the same error.
When trying to find a length of an empty list outside of the function, it works as it should: len([]) returns 0.

Here is my code:

```
def bitvector(n, k, vektor):
    if len(vektor) == n:
        if vektor.count(1) == k:
            print(vektor)
    bitvector(n, k, vektor.append(0))
    bitvector(n, k, vektor.append(1))


bitvector(1, 2 , [])
```

EDIT:

```
def bitvector(n, k, vektor):
    if len(vektor) > n:
        return
    if len(vektor) == n:
        print("test")
        if vektor.count(1) == k:
            print(vektor)
            return
    bitvector(n, k, vektor.append(1))
    bitvector(n, k, vektor.append(0))


bitvector(1, 2 , [])
```

It is supposed to get the length of the list, but instead it throws the following error:

TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Comment: `vektor` is None - it is not `[]` like you expect

Comment: `vektor.append` returns `None`, not the updated `list` value. Pass `vecktor + [0]` as the argument instead. (Or ensure that your recursive function will work properly  if you mutate an argument.)

Comment: You might want to do. `vektor + [0]` and `vektor + [1]`.

Comment: Also please post full code.

Comment: If you expect that `vektor` can be `list` or `None`, you can test `if len(vektor or []): ...` so that you can always handle a list

Comment: That is the full code, had an indentation mistake.
The problem is that the vektor is a None and not [] like @rdas mentioned.
How can I give an empty list to the function?

Comment: chepner and Poojan have showed you what to do.

Comment: You will hit infinite recursion when your `TypeError` is resolved. `print` does not `return` out of the function

Comment: Even if you fix the `.append` problem, your code will run forever without printing anything, because `bitvector(1, 2 , [])` will call `bitvector(1, 2 , [0])` which will call `bitvector(1, 2 , [0, 0])` etc. and no 1s gets added in finite time. (You should not make the recursive calls if `len(vektor)>=n`, methinks.)

Comment: The error comes from the first if-sentence. The .append() is not the problem. Also, I am trying to fix the TypeError problem, the infinite recursion problem is now solved.

Comment: Even if I give [1] as the input for the bitvector function (bitvector(1, 2, [1]), it still returns the same error: TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len().

Comment: Not sure why you don't wanna listen to all the people explaining here. vektor.append() is the problem. append always return None, so when you call bitvector(n, k, vektor.append(1)), you are effectively calling bitvector(n, k, None). Hence the problem you reported NoneType has no len()

Comment: I tried using different ways to append the list, also tried the ones mentioned above, and none of them worked.
Found out that I can give the function [0,0] as argument, and it can work with that. So I can't find where the error lies.

Comment: Of course, because in that case you return from function and never go to the bitvector(n, k, vektor.append(1))

Comment: Yeah gotta admit, that was a dumb idea. Found a solution. Instead of using a list, I used a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was not limited to use a certain Type, the I chose to use a string instead of the list.

```
def bitvector(n, k, vektor):
    vektor_list = list(vektor)
    if len(vektor) > n:
        return
    if len(vektor) == n:
        if vektor_list.count("1") == k:
            print(vektor)
            return
    bitvector(n, k, vektor + "0")
    bitvector(n, k, vektor + "1")
```

EDIT, optimized my code:

```
def bitvector(n, k, vektor):
vektor_list = list(vektor)
if vektor_list.count("1") > k:
    return
if len(vektor) == n:
    if vektor_list.count("1") == k:
        print(vektor)
        return
    else:
        return
bitvector(n, k, vektor + "0")
bitvector(n, k, vektor + "1")
```